# How to handle event.completed() in Dialog API Office JS

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-dialog-api

I am currently invoking a dialog from a button on the ribbon in Outlook. The dialog works fine without any issues, but the message "...add-in is working on your request" appears even after the dialog is opened/closed.

Here is how the dialog is invoked..

```
function openDialog(event) {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net', { height: 80, width: 92 },
        function (asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
            event.completed();
        }
    );
}

function processMessage(event) {
    event.completed();
}
```

[image: add-in message]

How to avoid this message ? Tried to close the event in the EventHandler callback(processMessage) as well but didn't work.

Comment: On which Outlook platform are you seeing this behavior (Windows, Mac, or Web)?

Comment: On Windows Client. Version 1908.

Comment: I was unable to repro the issue you are seeing. Would you be able to share your processMessage function? Calling event.completed() inside processMessage should dismiss the infobar even if the dialog is open. Does this issue repro acorss clients (i.e. in OWA as well)?

Comment: Even if add only event.completed() statement in the processMessage, the issue still exists. It is the same in OWA as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For addEventHandler, if you would like to complete the event when the dialog is closed, you can use the [DialogEventReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialog?view=word-js-preview#method-details) event, which is triggered when the dialog box has been closed or otherwise unloaded. Also, the handler function (processMessage) should use a different parameter name from event as to not overwrite the variable.

```
function openDialog(event) {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net', { height: 80, width: 92 },
        function (asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, processMessage);
            event.completed();
        }
    );
}

function processMessage(args) {
    event.completed();
}
```